# Webdriveragent getting installed and uninstalled while launching the inspector

Tags: automation, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to inspect an iOS app using appium inspector but the webdriveragent app is getting installed and uninstalled.

Comment: I a using M1 chip mac

Comment: Are you using the latest Appium version 1.22.3-4? You need it if you upgraded to Xcode 13.3.* and iOS 15.